# .htaccess and wordpress redirects problem

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have this structure in my site:

/

/portal  <--(WordPress Folder)

when someone enters www.example.com it should redirect to https://www.example.com/portal but shouldn't show portal, so, address bar should look like: https://www.example.com

As this is a WordPress + Woocomerce site I also need some redirects like:

http://www.example.com/carrito to 
https://www.example.com/carrito

Problem is that at this moment, when I input http://www.example.com/carrito it changes adress bar to https://www.example.com/portal/carrito

currently I have this .htaccess files:

**/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)? 
example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/portal/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /portal/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)? 
example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ portal/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

**/portal/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

# If we receive a forwarded http request from a proxy...
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http [OR]

# ...or just a plain old http request directly from the client
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

# Redirect to https version
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
# RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to update the code in htaccess file, I have mentioned in below,

```
RewriteEngine On

# If we receive a forwarded http request from a proxy...
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http [OR]

# ...or just a plain old http request directly from the client
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

# Redirect to https version
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
# RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**Follow the link for get the more details- https://in.godaddy.com/help/redirect-http-to-https-for-wordpress-on-linux-27904**

Comment: This works perfectly for sites that are on root folder, I solved it by transfering wordpress to root folder, and I abandoned the idea of having it on a subfolder.